# Display data using json in datatables codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, datatables

I want to display my data using json data format in datatables, but I am not getting any data in the table. Could anyone help me to display data in datatable through JSON?

This is my controller:

```
public function data_courses(){
    $result=$this->Users_model->get_active_courses();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
public function courses_list(){
    $this->authentication();
    $this->load->view('courses');
}
```

This is my view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="allcourses">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>
                Course Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Indian Price
            </th>
            <th>
                U S Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Course Duration
            </th>
            <th>
                Discount
            </th>
            <th>
                <center>Pick Course</center>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#allcourses').dataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [
                [5, 15, 20, 100, -1],
                [5, 15, 20, 100, "All"]
            ],
 "ajax": "Student/data_courses",
        "aoColumns": [
            {"data": "course_name"},
            {"data": "price_INR"},
            {"data": "price_USD"},
            {"data": "no_of_hours"},
            {"data": "discount"},
            {"data": "status"},
            { "bSortable": false }
        ]
    });
});
```

This is my model

```
public function get_active_courses(){
     $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('courses');
    $this->db->where('status',1);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();    
    }
```

My JSON data

```
{"data":[{"course_id":"1","course_name":" PHP","price_INR":"25,000","price_USD":"750","no_of_hours":"86","date":"2016-05-19 17:58:47","status":"1","discount":"5.89"},{"course_id":"5","course_name":"Java","price_INR":"15,000","price_USD":"650","no_of_hours":"25","date":"2016-05-14 07:59:24","status":"1","discount":"2.50"},{"course_id":"6","course_name":"Dot net","price_INR":"23,000","price_USD":"250","no_of_hours":"36","date":"2016-05-14 12:16:33","status":"1","discount":"5.63"},{"course_id":"7","course_name":"python","price_INR":"15000","price_USD":"650","no_of_hours":"78","date":"2016-05-14 19:25:34","status":"1","discount":"2.50"},{"course_id":"9","course_name":"HTML & CSS","price_INR":"28,000","price_USD":"980","no_of_hours":"78","date":"2016-05-14 19:31:16","status":"1","discount":"2.36"}]}
```

Comment: Could you please share the resulting json?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your json returns a "data" property with the tabular data as the value, i.e.:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {...},
        {...}
        ...
    ]
}
```

For this, simply change

```
public function data_courses(){
    $result=$this->Users_model->get_active_courses();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

To:

```
public function data_courses(){
    $result=$this->Users_model->get_active_courses();
    echo json_encode(array("data" => $result));
}
```

More info [Here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc)

update: You should also check that you have the same number of header columns in the html table (the `th` elements) than columns in the javascript. Currently, you have 7 columns defined in javascript but 6 header columns in html. Try removing the last `{ "bSortable": false }` in the columns definitions.

Comment: Thank you sebastianb actually I am new to JSONand datatables, if i change that columns to data i am getting empty tables but no data is displaying colud you help me

Comment: Try checking if the query (get_active_courses) actually returns something.

Comment: i have checked with last_query its displaying correct query @Sebastianb

Comment: But does the query return something? try using die(var_dump($result)) before the echo, or check the ajax response with developer tools in the browser.

Comment: I am getting data in JSON formate, but i want to display my data in tables in <td>s how can I ??

Comment: Could you please edit your original question and add the json that the query returns?

Comment: and btw, what version of datatables are you using? just noticed you're using 'ajax' property (available in API of 1.10) together with the legacy API (1.9).

Comment: hi i have added JSON formate data and my datatables version is DataTables 1.10.5

Comment: I edited the answer with one more thing (num of columns). Besides that, I don't really see anything else wrong...